# Passing a lambda function to a lambda function in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lambda-calculus

So I have a little challenge.

I'm trying to program this here:

[image]

Which with lambda calculus simplifies to 12.

I have the following Scheme script:

```
(
    define double (
        lambda x (
            + (car x) (car x)
        )
    )
)

(display 'Debug)
(newline)

(display (double 6))
(newline)


(
    define getTwelve (
        ((
            (lambda x (
                lambda y (
                    (display y)
                    (newline)
                    (x (x y))
                )
            ))
            double
        ) 3)
    )
)



(display getTwelve)

(newline)
(newline)
```

Which corresponds to this terminal output:

```
Debug
12
(3)
application: not a procedure;
 expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
  given: '(#<procedure:double>)
  arguments...:
   '(3)
```

So of course I thought 'it's because the parameter of double is a list instead of a number' but `car y` just changes the last line of the terminal output to `3`.

I think I'm interpreting the `Racket` terminal output wrong, but I don't know in which way. There is however the other possibility that passing a `lambda` function into a `lambda` function as a parameter is not allowed.

So my question is:  Which one is it?

Comment: Don't put a newline and indentation after `(`. It's very unusual Scheme style.

Comment: Noted. I was using it to tell the difference between a definition and an execution on the lambda, but you're completely right. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the parameter list after `lambda` should be a list of variables. You only use a single variable without a list if you want to allow a variable number of arguments to the procedure, which isn't the case here. If you do this, each variable will be bound to successive arguments, and you don't need to use `car` to get the value of the argument. So it should be:

```
(define double
    (lambda (x) 
        (+ x x)))
```

If you do this with `getTwelve` you should get the result you expect.

```
(define getTwelve
  ((((lambda (x)
       (lambda (y)
         (display y)
         (newline)
         (x (x y))))
     double) 3)))
```

You also had an extra set of parentheses around the body of the innermost `lambda`.

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/rA627K)